# ASM x86 - Move value into memory

Tags: memory, assembly, att

I'm using a 32 bit Linux system and I can't understand how to put a value into memory.
This is an example:

```
str:    .asciz "AAA"
p:    .long 0

.text
.globl  main

main:
    movl $str, p    #Save the address of str into p (?)
```

I know that I can do `movl $str, %eax` to store the str address inside the eax register, but I can't do the same thing with `p` because I receive a segmentation fault error.

I tried also this alternative, but the result is always a segmentation fault:

```
main:
call self
self:
    pop %ebp
    movl $str, (p-self) (%ebp)
```

Can someone explain to me how to use `mov` in the right way?
I'd like also to know if it's possible store the str address into p at compile time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me how to use mov in the right way?

It isn't about the `mov`. That's fine. You need to specify a section to put the data into. Add `.data` at the front of the program to put it in the `.data` section. Otheriwise, the data are put into the `.text` section by default, which is read-only on modern OSes. Writing to it leads to a Segmentation fault.

> I'd like also to know if it's possible store the str address into p at
>   compile time.

It is possible:

```
p: .long str
```